# Outlook needs 2-3 minutes to open a mail

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007

Since my last restart this morning my Outlook is gone to hell.
Every second email needs around 2-3 minutes to open.

I have no idea what caused that, I didn't install software, i didn't unsinstall software, I didn't install updates or something like that.

I have no idea where to begin to search!

How to start search for the error?

Things I have done to try to solve it:

- install all new updates and try again
- kill all not needed proceses and try again
- restart again and only start outlook
- kill all startup's, restart and only start outlook
- run spybot search and destroy
- run anti virus

Nothing helped.

---

A few things I noticed:

- Nothing changed on the system else then the outlook problems
- Every email I opened once (and waited 2-3 minutes) I can open again within seconds without problems

---

New Note:
 - The Problem only happens on brand new Email since the restart this morning. I opened ~50-100 Emails from the last weeks / month without problems!

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using?  Are your emails being dumped into a .pst file?

Comment: Sounds like your pst file might be corrupt, have you tried running scanpst on it? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-HA010075831.aspx

Comment: What kind of email account are you using? Exchange? POP? IMAP?  Are you accessing the mail via the Internet, or is it on the same LAN as you?  Have you checked the Windows Event Log for any strange or new errors?  Have you checked your disks for corruption (chkdsk)?

Comment: Scanpst find errors, but it seems not the errors I need, because the problems are still not solved.
I use 3 pop3 accounts.

Comment: If scanpst found errors then there are problems with the structure of the pst file.  How big is the pst file?  Maybe rebuilding it would be an option?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by attempting to run Outlook in safe mode.

You can do this by holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key whilst Outlook is starting.

If this fixes it, you have some sort of addon that is causing problems. See what you have installed recently and see if you can remove it.

If this doesn't fix it, are you using an IMAP server? In particular, Gmail - I have seen issues like this before and have been unable to resolve fully. Going in to `Offline Model` prevents the ability to do folder operations, but, it stopped the freezes.

Next if nothing else fixes it, all I can suggest is an extreme option of exporting all your messages then setting up a new Outlook profile and import your messages and account settings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
Safe Mode doesn't help, no I have no IMAP Server.

Any other ideas else then setting up everything new?

Answer (score 2):

Try first repairing Microsoft Office. Go to "Uninstall Software" and find Office 2007. Select "Change" and when the window opens, select "Repair".

Comment: If that doesn't solve the problem, close all office programs. In the search bar type "folder options" select the "view" tab and select the "show hidden files" radio button. Open my computer and go to C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft rename the "Outlook" folder to something like "(x)Outlook" then go to C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft and do the same for the "Outlook folder there. Then restart Outlook and set you email back up. If that doesn't work you can revert back to the original folders.

Comment: Repair did not work. Will try the next.